# c++ - specializing less<> and greater<>

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I am trying to implement an AVL-List-Container and want to give the programmer the possibility to pass via template a parameter to the container in order to influence the sorting order.

The STL containers (set, sort etc) allow to use pass the structs `less<>` and `greater<>` with an overloaded ()-operator as parameters.
I did not manage to pass a functor to my container.

The test scenario is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

namespace TEST_SPACE {

template< typename T, typename COMP_FUNC = ::std::less<T> >
class cTst {

  T data;
  T* data_ptr;

public:
  template< typename U = T >
  bool get_min_00( ) { }

  template< typename V,  typename FUNC = COMP_FUNC, bool dummy = false>
  bool get_min_01( V a, V b  ) {
  return (*FUNC) ( a, b );
  }
};  // class cTst
}   // namespace TEST_SPACE

int main() {

TEST_SPACE::cTst< int > obj_00;
obj_00.get_min_00< int >();     // working
obj_00.get_min_01< int > ( 2, 3 );  // working
obj_00.get_min_01< int,  ::std::greater<int>() > ( 2, 3 );
return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10). The compiler complains:

```
gcc -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic _tst-04.cpp 
_tst-04.cpp: In member function ‘bool TEST_SPACE::cTst<T, COMP_FUNC>::get_min_01(V, V)’:
_tst-04.cpp:31:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
  return (*FUNC) ( a, b );
        ^
_tst-04.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool TEST_SPACE::cTst<T, COMP_FUNC>::get_min_01(V, V) [with V = int; FUNC = std::less<int>; bool dummy = false; T = int; COMP_FUNC = std::less<int>]’:
_tst-04.cpp:62:37:   required from here
```

I searched the net and found no fitting / working solution for this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to the template must be a "typename COMP_FUNC", a type/class.

```
obj_00.get_min_01< int,  ::std::greater<int>() > ( 2, 3 );
```

"::std::greater()" is not a type, it is a constructor call, here. This should be:

```
obj_00.get_min_01< int,  ::std::greater<int> > ( 2, 3 );
```

Comment: Thx, Sam. I suggest that the parantheses is right, because the struct overloads the ()-operator. Removing the parantheses results in

Comment: _tst-04.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool TEST_SPACE::cTst<T, COMP_FUNC>::get_min_01(V, V) [with V = int; FUNC = std::less<int>; bool dummy = false; T = int; COMP_FUNC = std::less<int>]’

Comment: sorry:

_tst-04.cpp: In member function ‘bool TEST_SPACE::cTst<T, COMP_FUNC>::get_min_01(V, V)’:
_tst-04.cpp:31:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       return (*FUNC) ( a, b );
                    ^
_tst-04.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool TEST_SPACE::cTst<T, COMP_FUNC>::get_min_01(V, V) [with V = int; FUNC = std::less<int>; bool dummy = false; T = int; COMP_FUNC = std::less<int>]’:

Comment: @RainerStötter `*FUNC` is an error, you cannot dereference a typename . Maybe you meant `return FUNC()( a, b );`

Comment: Hello M.M. - both versions are allowed in C++. In C you call a function using a function pointer by explicitly dereferencing it using the * operator. Alternatively you may nowadays also just use the function pointer's instead of the funtion's name.

Comment: @RainerStötter, both are allowed for function pointers. A general function *object* (or functor) doesn't usually define unary `operator*`

Answer (score 0):

I found an interim solution for my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


template <typename T, typename CMP = std::less<T>, typename A1, typename A2>
bool getOrder_05( const A1&& a, const A2&& b, CMP func =  CMP( ) )
{
  return (func)( std::forward<A1>(a), std::forward<A2>(b) );
  //return new T(std::forward<A1>(a1), std::forward<A2>(a2));
}

class cStructure {

public:
cStructure( int x, std::string str = "" ) : m_int_value( x ) , m_str_value( str ) {}

friend std::less<cStructure >;
friend std::greater<cStructure >;
friend std::less<cStructure * >;

int GetIntValue() { return this->m_int_value; } ;
std::string GetStringValue() { return this->m_str_value; } ;

protected:
int m_int_value = 0;
std::string m_str_value;



};  // cStructure

namespace std {
template<>
struct less<cStructure> : public binary_function <cStructure , cStructure , bool>
{
public:

    bool operator()(const cStructure &a, const cStructure & b ) const
    {
    return a.m_int_value < b.m_int_value ;
    }

};
}

namespace std {
template<>
struct greater<cStructure> : public binary_function <cStructure , cStructure , bool>
{
public:

    bool operator()(const cStructure &a, const cStructure & b ) const
    {
    return a.m_int_value > b.m_int_value ;
    }

};
}

namespace std {
template<>
struct less<cStructure *> : public binary_function <cStructure *, cStructure *, bool>
{
public:

    bool operator()(const cStructure * a, const cStructure * b ) const
    {
    return a->m_int_value < b->m_int_value ;
    }


};  // less<cStructure *>
}

namespace std {
class lessByStringValue : public binary_function < cStructure, cStructure, bool >
{
public:

    bool operator()( cStructure * a, cStructure  * b ) const
    {
    return a->GetStringValue( ) < b->GetStringValue( ) ;
    }

};  // lessByStringValue<cStructure *>
}



int main()
{

  int set_value_00 = 20;

cStructure obj_00 = cStructure( 11, "Pizza Mare" );
cStructure obj_01 = cStructure(  7, "Ciabatta" );

cStructure *obj_02 = new cStructure( 14, "Pizza Margeritha");
cStructure *obj_03 = new cStructure(  8, "Cannelloni");
cStructure *obj_04 = new cStructure(  5, "Spagetthi");
cStructure *obj_05 = new cStructure( 10, "Pizza Napoli" );
cStructure *obj_06 = new cStructure( 12, "Pizza Funghi" );

bool value_05a = getOrder_05<cStructure>( obj_00, obj_01 );
bool value_05b = getOrder_05<cStructure * >( obj_02, obj_03 );
bool value_05c = getOrder_05<cStructure * >( &obj_00, obj_03 );
bool value_05d = getOrder_05<int>( 2, int(15) );
bool value_05e = getOrder_05<int, std::less<int> >( 2, int(15) );
bool value_05f = getOrder_05<cStructure *, std::less<cStructure *> >( &obj_00, obj_03 );
bool value_05g = getOrder_05<cStructure *, std::lessByStringValue >( &obj_00, obj_03 );


delete obj_02;
delete obj_03;
delete obj_04;
delete obj_05;
delete obj_06;


return 1;

}
```

It is an interim solution as it does not exactly what I wanted it to do: The template

```
template <typename T, typename CMP = std::less<T>, typename A1, typename A2>
bool getOrder_05( const A1&& a, const A2&& b, CMP func =  CMP( ) )
{
  return (func)( std::forward<A1>(a), std::forward<A2>(b) );
  //return new T(std::forward<A1>(a1), std::forward<A2>(a2));
}
```

expects the type's address and not the address of the ()-operator. Therefore I have to write

```
bool value_05f = getOrder_05<cStructure *, std::less<cStructure *> >( &obj_00, obj_03 );
bool value_05g = getOrder_05<cStructure *, std::lessByStringValue >( &obj_00, obj_03 );
```

instead of

```
bool value_05f = getOrder_05<cStructure *, std::less<cStructure *>() >( &obj_00, obj_03 );
bool value_05g = getOrder_05<cStructure *, std::lessByStringValue() >( &obj_00, obj_03 );
```

Maybe anybody knows another approach?